# How to alert on angular ui grid import file fail?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, csv, angular-ui-grid

I am using angular UI Grid to import a file.
I am using:

```
enableGridMenu: true,
importerDataAddCallback: function (grid, newObjects) {
```

When I import a file that isn't a csv I get the error:

> uncaught exception: UNEXPECTED_END_OF_RECORD at char...

I would like to have an alert  box popup if the import doesn't work correctly.
I found  **uiGridImporterService** which has the method, **alertError(grid, headerRow)**.

  I'm not sure if this is what I need.

So, how do I add an Alert if it fails?  
As a side question, can I check that it's importing a .csv file?

Comment: can you use `$q` to create a promise that can return an `err`?

Comment: Possibly.  The ui-grid-importer is built in functionality to ui-grid, so I really don't know where I would attempt to put the $q.  The importerDataAddCallback function is accessible, but only after the file is determined to be good.  Before that point, I don't know where to access the import process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code that alerts on a failed CSV import:

```
CSV.error = function (err){
    var msg = CSV.dump(err);
    CSV.reset();
    //alert("CSV import failed.");
    toastr["error"]("Import failed.");
    throw msg;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use $q**

By using $q you can return a promise that can fail or pass. On a fail in your case you can call an alert to popup.

**Example**

Taken from the [AngularJS documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

```
return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    if (okToGreet(name)) {
      resolve('Hello, ' + name + '!');
    } else {
      reject('Greeting ' + name + ' is not allowed.');
    }
  }, 1000);
});
```

On the faild promises return you could have your alert popup to tell the user the action has failed.